# Modify view to change audience

Tags: 2007, list-view, audiences

I created a view and chose the option `Create a Public View` in the Audience section of the *Create View* page.  I want to change that to `Create a Personal View` now, but the *Edit View* page doesn't give access to that section.

How do I go about doing that short of recreating it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new view based on that public view, you'll be able to set it to personal.  Then you can delete the public view.